# Why won't my Index.js file be recognized?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, debugging, react-native

I made a separate `Index.js` file to hold all the components that I want to export throughout the app I'm creating. I thought the file path I'm taking would be correct but instead...

I'm getting an error that says:

> Could not resolve
>   '/User/user/projects/Something/src/components/components' as a file
>   nor as a folder (null)

[image: screenshot of directory path]

How can I fix this?

Here's `LoginForm.js`:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { TouchableOpacity, StyleSheet, View, Text ,Button } from 'react-native';
import { UserInput } from './components';

class LoginForm extends Component {
  render() {
    return(
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <UserInput/>
          <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button}>
            <Button
              title="Press Me"
            />
          </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingHorizontal: 10
  },

  button: {
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#DDDDDD',
    padding: 10
  }
});

export default LoginForm;
```

Here's `Index.js`:

```
export * from './UserInput';
export * from './LoginForm';
```

Comment: inlined the image and changed error message to quote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the current working directory of `LoginForm.js` , there is no `components` folder.
From your script, you want `UserInput` component in the `LoginForm` component.

You can simply do it

```
import { UserInput } from './UserInput';
```

Right use of `index.js` of `components` folder is when you want to import the  selected  component of folder's in other directory's component's

**update :**

in the `LoginForm` component do

```
import  UserInput  from './UserInput'; //default  export
```

Comment: Ah ok, I see what you're saying.  A while back I was following this tutorial that did what I'm trying to do now.  He used an index.js to place all the components he's going to export, and then defined the way those components will be retrieved just by calling the folders name.

Comment: By the way, I'm still getting an error when I use `import { UserInput } from './UserInput';`.  The error says to check the render method of `LoginForm.js` but I'm pretty sure that's rendered correctly and that I supposedly forgot to export the component.

Comment: Please check are u doing named  export or default `UserInput `

Comment: I'm using export default, the same way I'm exporting it in my original post.

Comment: Thank you, sir.  I understand this concept now.